# How to perform a segue from TableView programmatically

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have a TableView on a ViewController and want to segue to another ViewController by pressing any row. My Code for this is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowDetailView", sender: Cell)
}
```

I have connected both ViewControllers in the storyboard and named the storyboard segue identifier "ShowDetailView", but i get an error with this code?
Can somebody give me an advise?

Comment: It seems to me that `Cell` is undefined - but you may actually want to provide the error message

Comment: can you will try sender is nil

Comment: 2019-02-08 22:18:07.386326+0100 SmallApps[48231:6498227] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SmallApps.DetailViewController 0x7f91b0e0b5c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key itemLabel.'

Comment: you added an outlet named `itemLabel` and removed it , so clear it's connection in IB

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to send clicked cell for getting the content , so replace

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowDetailView", sender: Cell)
```

with

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowDetailView", sender:arr[indexPath.row])
```

Where `arr` is the table's dataSource array , if you don't need to send anything do

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowDetailView", sender:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because in the destination, “detailsViewController” there was a subView called ‘itemLabel’ that you either delete or rename it in code and forgot to disconnect its outlet from UI. Right click on it and hit X on itemLabel outlet